# iTunes Connect developer profile submission

Tags: ios, distribution, app-store-connect

It has just occurred to me that I did not set up my project properly in Xcode before submitting an update to my existing app in iTunes Connect.

In Xcode, under the build properties, I have set the Code Signing Identity to developer. I archived that build and then submitted it to iTunes Connect, but choosing the Distribution certificate from the dropdown during the submission process.

Does this mean that part of my app is signed with the developer certificate and the other with the distribution certificate? Or, is the whole thing signed with the distribution certificate.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the link. The posts are similar.

From the link, it sounds that you can do it but the developer profile has 'get-task-allow' set to true (so the debugger can connect to it), whereas the distribution profile has 'get-task-allow' set to false.

Other than this (which could be bad), are there any other problems that may arise from building with the developer profile, distributing to the AppStore with the distribution profile?

Getting back to my original question - which profile is the app built with? Developer, distribution or both?